# How can I add a 'back' button to external page opened in new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

I'm sorry for the broad question, but I have not clue where to start.

I have an optin form in my website generated through MailChimp. When the user optins I get him to a customized page. The page opens in a new tab.

I have find solutions like these:

```
<input type="button" value="Go Back From Where You Came!" onclick="history.back(-1)" />

<FORM><INPUT Type="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></FORM>
```

They would work in internal navigation, but not for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: you need a scripting language to redirect your page. It could be possible to do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this.  The browser history is tied to the individual window, so you can make the window go backwards or farwards in history but you cannot open a new window and direct to the first window's previous page.  You cannot even get what the previous URL actual was, as this is a security feature.

The best you can do is to keep track of the previous page of your site via a cookie or session variable and then use javascript to popup the window with the stored URL.

Comment: Hi @Crayon that's what I thought too after researching. I just thought I should give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the original page is static or a variable in your webpage template, you can add an `<a>` tag like so:

```
<a href="/pageYouShouldHaveCameFrom">
<button type="button" name="button" onClick="javascript:history.go('/pageYouShouldHaveCameFrom');">Back</button>
</a>
```

When the page is not internal and there is no history it will go to the link defined in href.
As said by Crayon Violent more complex webpages should use cookies or session variables.